# How to intercept user defined message twice?

Tags: delphi, postmessage

I'm using a component that internally has a KeyDown handler, which sends a user defined PostMessage(WM_GROUPUNGROUP), and also has a custom message handler to handle WM_GROUPUNGROUP.

I want my app to do something after this message handler has executed, without modifying the component code.

(How) Can this be done?

Comment: Make an interposer class for that component, catch that `WM_GROUPUNGROUP` message and fire a new event like for instance `OnGroupUngroup` which you'll bind in your application.

Comment: @TLama That only works if you can interpose all the instantiation

Comment: @David, I don't get your note. If you're able to change the `WindowProc` as you suggests, why wouldn't you be able to add one unit (containing that interceptor) into the uses clause ? And that interception will apply once and for all instances used in that particular unit.

Comment: @Tlama In my case that component is indeed already used/created (once) by the form this is all taking place on.

Comment: @TLama It may be that the instance is instantiated in a class to which you cannot control the source. For example it might be instantiated by code in a runtime package that you cannot or do not want to re-compile. An interposer class requires a change of instantiated type which can only happen at the point of instantiation. Using WindowProc, for example, allows for changes in behaviour to be effected part way through an object's life.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to achieve this is via the `WindowProc` property.

Simply supply your own window procedure by assigning to `WindowProc` on the instance you want to hook. You'll need to take a copy to the previous value of `WindowProc` so that you can make sure that the original handling is carried out.

Roughly it goes like this:

```
type
  TMyClass = class
  ....
    FOldWindowProc: TWndMethod;
    procedure NewWindowProc(var Message: TMessage);
  ....
  end;
```

To redirect the window procedure you do this:

```
FOldWindowProc := SomeControl.WindowProc;
SomeControl.WindowProc := NewWindowProc;
```

Then implement the new window procedure like this:

```
procedure TMyClass.NewWindowProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  FOldWindowProc(Message);
  if Message.Msg = WM_GROUPUNGROUP then 
    ....
end;
```

When you are done with the control, put the old window procedure back in place:

```
SomeControl.WindowProc := FOldWindowProc;
```

Another way to do it is to take advantage of the fact that the message is queued. You can add an `Application.OnMessage` handler, most likely by using a `TApplicationEvents` object. This will get a look at all queued messages. However, `OnMessage` fires before the message is dispatched to the control which sounds like it may be the wrong way round for you.

Comment: Thanks, that worked great. I hook the components' WindowProc in my FormCreate, and to keep it clean reassign to FOldWindowPoc in the FormDestroy.

Comment: You can set 'handled' to true and dispatch the message in the OnMessage handler manually (DispatchMessage) and then do your work if execution order is important.